# What is the best way to expose my server's API?

Tags: .net, web-services, api, remoting

I have a .NET Windows service that needs to expose an API. I am using remoting now during development process.

Right now all my methods accept and return XML. I already have a lot of custom serialization and deserialization code for the needed objects.

None of these objects are very large.

I want to make my API available to many languages easily.

I have considered hosting a web service inside the service and also just plain sockets.

What is the best way to expose this API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use WCF, hosted in the service. It's clean, flexible, and supported.